# How do I structure an Ember.js app so I can access application state from itemControllers?

Tags: ember.js

I have a collection of models, each of which stores a bit of application-persistent state on the controller. I want to access this state elsewhere in the app, but I'm not sure exactly how.

[Here's a JS Bin with a stripped-down version of the app](http://jsbin.com/riwegefiyasa/17/edit) which demonstrates what I'm trying to do: On the "Boxes" route, I want to display a count of the number of clicked widgets, but from `BoxController` I don't know how to get access to the `WidgetController`s that have that property.

If I understand the guides correctly, I should be able to [use `needs` to inject one controller into another](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/), but this doesn't really apply when I'm using `itemController` to wrap each model in its own controller instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break it up into 3 parts...

---

1) Add a computed property to the `App.WidgetsController` the contains the checked widgets. Something like

```
clickedWidgets: Ember.computed.filterBy('@this', 'hasBeenClicked', true)
```

---

2) Add `needs: ['widgets']` to the `App.BoxController`

---

3) Change the `clickedWidgets` computed property of the `App.BoxController` to get the list of clickedWidgets from the `App.WidgetsController` and the filter that list by widgets which match the box.

```
clickedWidgets: function() {
  return this.get('controllers.widgets.clickedWidgets')
    .filterBy('box', this.get('model')).length;
}.property('controllers.widgets.clickedWidgets.[]')
```

---

You can see a working bin here: http://jsbin.com/yizafe/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, yes `needs:['widgets']` is way to go: http://jsbin.com/tunuj/1/edit?html,js,output